# Как сделать проверку на PyMysql на наличие одинакового имени

Tags: python, pymysql

Есть переменная name, в которую вводиться текст, как проверить есть ли такой элемент в БД и если есть, то написать ошибку, нет пропустить дальше

Comment: Сделать запрос в БД к нужной таблице с условием отбора по равенству проверяемого поля заданному значению, и получить количество отобранных записей. Если "такой элемент в БД" присутствует - значение будет ненулевое.

Comment: можно сделать поле name уникальным, при вставке будет ошибка как раз

Comment: Я работаю на python, Мне нужно как то будет вывести ошибку

Comment: Eugene Dennis, дело говорит. А для обработки ошибки используйте try: except Error:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Придумал вот такое решение

```
# Проверяем на наличие уникальность Имени Фамилии
        try:
            with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                sql = "SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE name = %s "
                cursor.execute(sql, (self.name1))
                self.resultname = cursor.fetchall()

        finally:
            pass


        # Выводим ошибку о неоригинальности аккаунта
        if len(self.resultname) > 0:
            self.errors.append("Данный аккаунт зарегистрирован")`
```